# Go to an id from the tab in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue.

I have 5 tabs and I switch between them by clicking on the tabs. That works fine.

I've made an `<a>` tag in one of the tab contents so
that when i click on it, it should go to tab 2 by its ID

```html
    <a href="@Url.Content("#section-iconbox-2")">next tab</a>
```

but nothing happened!!!!
and the address bar is http://localhost:28189/home/webdesign#section-iconbox-2

Answer (score 0):

Fragment are not sent to the server. A fragment is anything that follows the `#` sign. You need to make a querystring instead, like:
http://localhost:28189/home/webdesign?section=section-iconbox-2

Querystrings are sent to the server.